# Find the length of the longest continuous stretch of a single number in an array

Tags: javascript

Here is the full description of the problem:

//Write a function which takes a list of numbers and returns the length of the
// longest continuous stretch of a single number. For example, on the input [1,7,7,3],
// the correct return is 2 because there are two 7's in a row. On the input
// [1,7,7,3,9,9,9,4,9], the correct return is 3, since there are three 9’s in a row.

Here is my solution:

```js
let sequenceChecker = (arr) => {

  let finalNum = 0;
  let secondPass = false;

  const bigestNumber = arr.sort()[arr.length - 1]
 
 arr.forEach(num => {

  if(num === bigestNumber){
     finalNum++  
  }

  else if(num != bigestNumber && finalNum > 0 ){
     secondPass = true
    
  }

  else if (secondPass == true && num === bigestNumber){
   finalNum = 0
  } 

 })
  return finalNum
}

console.log((sequenceChecker([1,7,7,3])).toString());

console.log((sequenceChecker([1,7,7,3,9,9,9,4,9])).toString());
```

I really don't understand why my code won't solve this problem. The first else if the statement never gets executed but the statement should evaluate to true and the code inside should execute.

Comment: `I really don't understand why my code won't solve this problem` ... because its not logical.

Comment: `.sort()` mutates the array (is in place)

Comment: Side notice. This is very generous approach `const bigestNumber = arr.sort()[arr.length - 1]` to get maximum value.

Comment: `the correct return is 3, since there are three 9’s in a row.` means if you sort the numbers you will break this correct return since there is a 4th "9" otherwise unsorted

Comment: I would take a step back and think about how you would solve this problem without a computer. Do you need to sort the array? Do you need the largest number? What's the point of a "second pass"? The answers to these questions should inform you as to what you minimally need to find the answer.

Comment: Instead of using sorting, you need to track the prior number, the current count of this number, and be able to archive the current count into another variable if the prior number doesn't match. Then you'd reset the current count to 1 and set the prior number again.

Comment: Agree with chazsolo, rush jobs dont always work

Comment: @chazsolo Thanks for answering! So I added a second pass assuming that the same number has a second sequence that is longer, ex: [1,7,7,3,9,9,9,4,9,9,9,9,9] then the correct return value would be 5.

Comment: @GetSet Oh! Yeah I didn't realize that sort() would mutate the array

Comment: There is no need to find the "highest" value. As pluto mentions, you are essentially counting sequentially non-unique values, and storing accordingly to a map.

Comment: at most this takes 5 lines of code. Maybe 6.

Comment: @SebastianDelima I think that should clue you in to what I mean - what if there is a third group, like `[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]`? You can't possibly catch all edge cases with if/else statements and flags. What is good is that you are iterating over the array with `forEach` - by the end of that loop you should have your answer (keeping in mind that `forEach` does not mutate or return anything)

Comment: @GetSet 5 lines? Wow, maybe one day I could be at that level.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
i checking the number of the sequence with the previous e increment the count in a variable

```
var arr = [1,7,7,3,9,9,9,4,4,4,4,4,4,9,9,9,9,9,9,9];
    
var prev; 
var count=0; 
var finalnum=0;

$.each(arr, function(index,num){

  if(prev != num) {
    prev = num;
    finalnum = (finalnum <= count ? count : finalnum);
    count = 1;
  }
  else {
    count = count + 1;
  }
  
  if(index == (arr.length - 1))
  {
    finalnum = (finalnum <= count ? count : finalnum);
  }    

});
console.log(finalnum);
```

Comment: Thanks! user2232273

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this. Create one function that return the length of the stretch by a number, It will return -1 if the array does not include the number.
Then, I would just compare the returns for each number and return the biggest number.

```js
const getLongestStretch = (arr, number) => {
  if (!arr.includes(number)) return -1;

  const filteredArrayLength = arr.filter(
    (n, i) => n === number && (arr[i - 1] === number || arr[i + 1] === number)
  ).length;

  if (filteredArrayLength === 0) return 1;

  return filteredArrayLength;
};

const sequenceChecker = (arr) =>
  arr.reduce(
    (result, number) => Math.max(result, getLongestStretch(arr, number)),
    1
  );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
arr =  [1, 7, 7, 3, 9, 9, 9, 4, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9];
let count = 1;
let journal = new Map();
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if(arr[i] == arr[i+1]) {
       ++count; 
   }else {
       if(journal.get(arr[i]) < count || !journal.get(arr[i])) {
           journal.set(arr[i], count);
       }
       count = 1;
   }
}
console.log(journal)  // Map(5) {1 => 1, 7 => 2, 3 => 1, 9 => 5, 4 => 1}
```